# Woocommerce My Account Page Nav Menu Doesn’t Work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-rest-api

Everytime if I change the shop page in woocommerece setting or I remove the downloads menu item in woocommerece setting the my account menu stop working, clicking on endpoint links (e.g. /edit-account/ or /customer-logout/) may appear to do nothing except refresh the page and add the endpoint to the url but nothing changes or show?

see below:
see screen shot when clicking on subscriptions nothing show same with all the menu items it should show "there are no subscription"

[image: see screen shot when clicking on subscriptions nothing show same with all the menu items it should show "there are no subscription"]

I Installed a plugin to edit the shop page called "ShopLentor – WooCommerce Builder for Elementor & Gutenberg" tried to disable it with no luck, the issue seems to happens everytime I touch the shop page or the endpoints, even though I return to the old setting, the issue keep happenning the only way to fix it is to go back and restore the website before making the change and thats make me loose all my work I did after.

Comment: I just disabled the shoplentor plugin and flushed the permalinks by going to settings and just clicking save and the same issue still exists, I'm trying just to use the default My Account menu that comes with woocommerce, I'm not changing it in anyway, what I'm changing is the default shop page in woo setting and that seems to break the my account menu.

Answer (score -1):

Because you did not add any template page for this endpoint.
use following code to add new endpoint:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'eskano_test', 40);
function eskano_test($menu_links)
{
    $menu_links = array_slice($menu_links, 0, 1, true) + array('test' => 'test') + array_slice($menu_links, 1, NULL, true);
    return $menu_links;
}
    
    
add_action('init', 'eskano_endpoint_test');
function eskano_endpoint_test()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('test', EP_PAGES);
}
    
add_action('woocommerce_account_test_endpoint', 'asrar_test_endpoint_content');
function asrar_test_endpoint_content()
{
    echo do_shortcode('');
}
```

Note1: change test to endpoint name `<br>`

Note2: you can use shortcode of elementor to view or custom page template

Comment: Kindly, this doesn't answer the OP issue. Note that your answer code already exists in Stack Overflow, as an accepted complete working code version.